# Is there any way to load compressed data with d3.tsv?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, nvd3.js

My data is big - (10 - 20 mb), so any compression like gzip will be awesome.

But after reading the D3 API documentation, it didnot mention how to load compressed file for d3.csv

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

Any tips?

Comment: In many cases this will be done automatically and transparently by the webserver.

Comment: Could you explain it in more details?

Comment: E.g. [mod_gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_gzip).

Comment: mod_gzip is for html/css/js only. I cannot find a way to use it with D3.

Comment: You can compress JSON as well this way. D3 does not provide any functions to read compressed data.